# social-share-button gem with html_safe not working in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used the social-share-button, Gem.

I want to share my website content to social site with some decoration, but it is not using HTML. It prints the `<b>` and `<i>` tags instead of making the text bold and italic.

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(raw("<b>#{job.title}</b>").html_safe, :url => "google.com" ) %>
```

Comment: Removed "Thanks" and fixed formatting

Comment: @JNYRanger What you want to say?

Comment: That's an auto comment from the review queue for editing your post.  Typically on SO you should not include superfluous comments in your question, which was my "editor comment".

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, you can find that `raw` is just a wrap version for `html_safe`. Normally, you don't need to call the both at sametime. see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw)

I saw the code [here](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/master/lib/social_share_button/helper.rb#L26), there is already a `raw` in the end of function `social_share_button_tag`. So I can just remove your `raw` and `html_safe` :

```
<%= social_share_button_tag("<b>#{job.title}</b>", :url => "google.com" ) %>
```

I guess you want blod your `job.title` with html `<b>`. You can make it in CSS. like that:

```
.social-share-button {
  .ssb-icon {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```